# Replacing only certain spaces in javascript with non spaces

Tags: javascript, substr, charat

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    console.log("replacing " + character + " at " + index);
  return this.substr(0, index) + character +     this.substr(index+character.length);
}
var reg = new RegExp("[01]{8,}");
var inner = "Non Binary Text 01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 non binary text.";
    inner = inner.replace(" ", "");
    for(var iii = 0; iii < 5; iii++){
    var pos =  inner.search(reg);
    for (var i=pos; i < inner.length; i++) {
        if(inner.charAt(i) == "1" || inner.charAt(i) == "0") continue;
        else if(inner.charAt(i) == " "){

                inner = inner.replaceAt(i, "");
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }}

    inner = inner.replace(/[01]{8}/g, function(v) { 
return String.fromCharCode( parseInt(v,2) ); 

});
//alert(inner);
console.log(inner);
```

Here's a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qjpgaz5h/ Issue i'm having is I'm wanting to remove spaces in between the blocks of binary but not between non binary but for whatever reason replacing the character is not working and I can't figure out why, if i replace the space with literally anything other than a nonspace it works fine.

What I wanted was to remove spaces so to turn

> Non Binary Text 01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 non binary text.

to

> Non Binary Text 01110100011001010111001101110100 non binary text.

Comment: You want to remove spaces between each 8 bits?

Comment: Please describe actually what you want to do.

Comment: Showing expected result would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `/([01]{8})\s+([01]{8})/g` like:

```
inner = inner.replace(/([01]{8})\s+(?=[01]{8})/g, "$1");
```

This will match a number of spaces `\s+` surrounded by a 8 bits block. We replace the `block`-`spaces`-(?=`block`) with `block`(`$1`) where `$1` means the first **group** (the first thing between spaces). The second group (`(?[01]{8})`) is a lookahead group s it's not included in the match.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var inner = "Non Binary Text 01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 non binary text.";

console.log("Before: '" + inner + "'");

inner = inner.replace(/([01]{8})\s+(?=[01]{8})/g, "$1");

console.log("After: '" + inner + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below regex to replace spaces between binary digits,

```
("Non Binary Text 01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 non binary text.").replace(/([01]+)\s(\d)/g,"$1$2")
```

This regex finds binary digits string with space after that and replaces it without space.